# access controller's object attributes in view page in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ROR and learning it. In my controller I have an admins
record and I am passing that admin object to the admin's view page to
get the name of the admin. But when I try to access the name it 
showing a error:

`undefined method 'name' for :current_admin:Symbol`

Please help..
Please find my code below

```
Sessions Controller

def create
  admin=Admin.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if admin && admin.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    redirect_to(admins_index_path(:current_admin=>admin))
  end
end
```

In view page of index_admin

Comment: Is your authentication from scratch?  or do you use a authentication gem like devise, omniauth or something else?

Comment: I doubt very much that the shown part of the code is the reason for the error. Please show admins controller and view code.

Comment: I am using devise gem for sign up.. But for sign in I am writing it from scratch. Not inheriting from Devise controller

Answer (score 0):

In your action for `index_admin` you need to get an admin object from your param. The value of a param is usually just a string.

```
def create
  admin=Admin.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if admin && admin.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    redirect_to(admins_index_path(:current_admin => admin.id))  # pass the id, not the object
  end
end

def index_admin
  @current_admin = Admin.find(params[:current_admin])
end
```

In you index_admin.html.erb:

```
Hi <%= @current_admin.name %>
```